# Google map overlay for south pole

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was trying to create custom overlay for south pole on google map. However, it was not possible to create accurate overlay. I am working on a project where i need to plot many marks on south pole. We will be getting series of longitude and latitude of south pole and we need to plot that into a map. As google does not have a map for south pole, we need to create a overlay or tiles on google. I have tried both of them however, not successful. Please let me know any idea. I can send you some example that i have done. I have followed this example below. However, can't get what we need because of destortion as well south pole right at the bottom of the map where it is completely grayed out on google map.

```
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image 

   https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=google+map&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-a&ie=UTF-8&ei=5UBVUrm1OITI0QXJ6IGwBw&ved=0CAoQ_AUoAg
```

Comment: Polar navigation/plotting is an age-old problem requiring a different approach and different maths from non-polar. Google sensibly stay well away from it.

Answer (score 0):

The map projection from Google doesn't work for the poles. In my opinion you need a transverse mercator projection. It uses the great circle.